# Is the bank https://silverexchangebank.com scam or real

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, scams

Is the bank `https://silverexchangebank.com` real or scam as they are asking 365$ amount to transfer funds from my Indian account. They are saying that we need to buy VAT as it is in UK and it is refundable. I have created account in `https://www.silverexchangebank.com/app/` from as said by clevertech enterprises company who gave me work and they said the amount is transferred to this bank. I am able to see the amount in dollars but not able to do any transcation. we can enroll directly from the website. Please let me know whether the bank is real or scam?

Comment: whenever you're being asked to pay money to get money, especially from some questionable source - it is very likely a scam.

Comment: @umapendyam - If you're concerned about this bank being a scam, why did you give them a good review? See here:

https://www.scamadviser.com/account/profile/998630

Answer (score 12):

Tl;dr likely scam. Chances are any "fee" you send them will absolutely **not** be refunded, and you will never see it again.

---

It looks somewhat suspicious, at a quick look. They have 5,430 "happy" customers, yet they have over 10K successful projects? And they've been in business for 15 years?

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Silver+Exchange+Bank) yields no information about them, which is rather unlikely for a real bank that's been in business for 15 years.

The social media icons at the bottom of the page all go to the base page (LinkedIn home, Facebook home, etc.), not a page for their bank. This also indicates it's a generic web template that someone used (and didn't finish setting up), which is odd for a bank that's been real for 15 years.

Their [about page](https://www.silverexchangebank.com/about) says 25 years, whereas their home page only says 15 years.

One of their testimonials contains "I recently opened an account with Customers Bank and their representatives were extremely helpful". A [search for that](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+recently+opened+an+account+with+Customers+Bank+and+their+representatives+were+extremely+helpful%22) reveals many similar sites, further indicating it isn't legit.

---

Red flags:

- Their website looks like a stock template, and is inconsistent
- The numbers don't make sense
- They require you to send them a large "fee"
- There is no information about this "bank" that's supposidly over a decade old

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time and telling the facts

Comment: Another data point worth adding: a WHOIS query for `silverexchangebank.com` returns `Creation Date: 2023-06-27T00:54:39Z`, which in English means that the domain was registered less than three months ago. Unless they recently went through a complete rename&rebrand, it's unthinkable that they could have operated for 15 years without a website. And had they rebranded just a few weeks ago, there would be a massive banner about that on the website or all their existing customers would get super confused about what happened to their bank.