# Is Dafexcounty bank legit or scam?

Tags: united-states, scams, online-banking, wire-transfer, transfer

I received the payment for my task on Dafexcounty. However, in order to transfer money to another bank. I need to avail VAT Code or they say Virtual Account Token Coin worth 150$. They said that I can't make any transfer even though it is the same bank withouth the VAT Code.

Comment: If you have to pay money to get "your" money, it's a scam. See e.g. [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/158252)

Comment: Adding that while the linked answers may talk of "COT fees", they apply equally to any other acronym-based fee that no-one's ever heard of, as a necessary step to get "your" money.

Comment: If it's legitimate, they can deduct the fee from the money they send you. If you have to pay first, it's a scam.